# Batch Apex for Counting number of Contacts associated with Account

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex

I am developing one Batch apex which will count number of Contacts associated with Account object.It will store the count in a field "No_of_Contacts" on Account. I am confuse in how can i write SOQL query and how it will execute.

Thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple way to wrap this up in a Batchable. All the Batchable mechanism is being used for is to divide up the Accounts into blocks.

```
public class MyBatchable implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {

    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([select Id from Account order by Name]);
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<Account> scope) {
        Account[] updates = new Account[] {};
        for (AggregateResult ar : [
                select AccountId a, count(Id) c
                from Contact
                where AccountId in :scope
                group by AccountId
                ]) {
            updates.add(new Account(
                    Id = (Id) ar.get('a'),
                    No_of_Contacts__c = (Decimal) ar.get('c')
                    ));
        }
        update updates;
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    }
}
```

If you have only a small number of Contacts per Account you can run this with a largish batch size, say the default of 200. But if you have more than 50,000 Contacts related to any Account this will still fail with even a batch size of 1 because the [governor limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm) apply to each `execute` method call.

**PS**

To run the Batchable it's:

```
Database.executeBatch(new MyBatchable(), 50);
```

where the last argument is how many Account object to pass per call of the Batchable's `execute` method. See the [Database.executeBatch](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_executeBatch_2) documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Keith c. Can you tell me how to run Schedule class

Comment: @ShantanuMahajan See the "PS".

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query

```
SELECT AccountId,Count(Id) FROM Contact GROUP BY AccountId
```

Comment: Thank you, Can you help me getting it done? Because i am confused about how should i write code.